# Fill a table when a item changed in a drop down list razor mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I want to fill a table with the data of my database when the selected item of my drop down list changed.
I think with a javascript but I don't know how search the selected item in my database and fill the table.

Comment: this post may help you figure it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371515/mvc3-dropdownlist-json-selected-issue you will need to use some form of get using jquery to post the seleted dropdown list item to you MVC action. Then consume the data and pop it in a table

Comment: post your code what you tried....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mvc/razor, then your project definitely involves jQuery. You might use an Ajax call to your controller's action like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#YourDropDownId").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
     url: "YourController/PopulateDetails",
     data: 'id=' + $(this).val(), // Send value of the drop down change of option
     dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
     success: function(data)
     {
        // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
     }
   });
  });
});
```

Your method should return JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult PopulateDetails(string id)
{
    // implementation here to return table data
    .....

    return Json(tableResultModel);
}
```

NB: If you're just looking for a way to get the selected value. then again jQuery can help; You can either use:

```
$("#YourDropDownId option:selected").text();
```

or

```
$("#YourDropDownId").val();
```